# Saleslogix ADODB

Tags: php, adodb, saleslogix

I am working on a data bridge project that will transfer data between SalesLogix (OLEDB), Sqlite 3 and Pick/D3. To complete the project, I am looking at ADODB. This project is part of a much bigger CRM project which the company has chosen The vendor that we are dealing with wants me to use Visual Studio 2013 and a .NET language. Most of the business intelligence is already in Php.

Here is my test Php ADODB CLI program:

```
$crlf = "\r\n";

// connection string
$cs = 'Provider=SLXOLEDB.1;Password=XX;Persist Security Info=True;';
$cs .= 'User ID=admin;Initial Catalog=PRIDE;Data Source=CRMAP;';
$cs .= "Extended Properties='PORT=1706;LOG=ON;CASEINSENSITIVEFIND=ON;";
$cs .= "AUTOINCBATCHSIZE=1;SVRCERT=;'";

try
   {
   $db = ADONewConnection('ado');
   $db->debug = true;
   }
catch(exception $e)
   {
   print "ADONewConnection failed$crlf";
   var_dump($e);
   adodb_backtrace($e->gettrace());
   }

try
   {
   $db->Connect($cs);
   }
catch(exception $e)
   {
   print "connect failed$crlf";
   var_dump($e);
   adodb_backtrace($e->gettrace());
   }
?>
```

I am running this on a Windows 7 PC with Php 5.3.10 installed and the most recent release of ADODB. I am trying to connect to the SalesLogix application server. SalesLogix has an OLE provider and I am attempting to use the ADO generic driver of ADODB on top of that. I should also say that VB .NET is able to connect to the SalesLogix application server using the same connection string as above. When I run my Php program, I get:

```
version=6.1
cs=Provider=SLXOLEDB.1;Password=XX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=admin;
Initial Catalog=PRIDE;Data Source=CRMAP;Extended Properties='PORT=1706;LOG=ON;
CASEINSENSITIVEFIND=ON;AUTOINCBATCHSIZE=1;SVRCERT=;'

exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Microsoft OLE DB Service Components

Description: Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB
specification.' in C:\wamp\www\CRM\Php\adodb\drivers\adodb-ado5.inc.php:117

Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\CRM\Php\adodb\drivers\adodb-ado5.inc.php(117):
com->Open('Provider=SLXOLE...')

#1 C:\wamp\www\CRM\Php\adodb\adodb.inc.php(550): 
ADODB_ado->_connect('Provider=SLXOLE...', '', '', '')

#2 C:\wamp\www\CRM\Php\crm-test1.php(28): 
ADOConnection->Connect('Provider=SLXOLE...')
```

My question is: What form does the ADODB connection string have to be in and how can I get this working?

TIA,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following article regarding the format of the SalesLogix/Infor CRM connection string:

[Understanding the SalesLogix OLE DB Connection String](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?id=35&articleid=7)

Although this article was written for versions 6.1 and previous, most if not all should still hold true for the most recent versions (8.1 at the time of this comment).